# Generating symmetric i.i.d distributed random numbers (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to generate an matrix drawn from a symmetric i.i.d distribution over integers from the range (0,3) (Integers 0 to 3 having the same probability of being drawn (1/4)). I looked at different numpy.random sampling but I'm not sure which one is appropriate.

Any suggestions on sampling identically distributed integers?

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

m = np.random.randint(low=0,high=4,size=(4,4))
```

note the the first number is inclusive, and the second is exclusive, and the last gives the dimensions:

```
In [35] m
Out[35]: 

array([[0, 3, 2, 3],
       [0, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 3, 1],
       [2, 3, 0, 3]])
```

note the the first number is inclusive, and the second is exclusive, and the last gives the dimensions.